# Convert Set<V> to Map<String, Set<String>

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, collect

I have following collection:

```
Set<Map.Entry<Event, Long>> entries
```

Event POJO:

```
public class Event{
    private long epoch; 
    private List<Pair<String, String> eventParams; 
}
```

I want to convert entries collection to `Map<String, Set<String>>`

Example:

```
List<Pair<String, String> eventParams = Arrays.asList(Pair.of("abc","123"), Pair.of("abc","456"));
```

Converted collection:

```
Map<String, Set<String>> converted = ["abc", ["123", "456"]]
```

I tried following:

```
entries.stream().flatMap(x -> x.getKey().getEventParams().stream())
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Pair::getKey, Collectors.toSet(Pair::getValue)));
```

However, I am getting error: **toSet in Collectors cannot be applied**.

What is the correct way of doing this ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Replace

```
Collectors.toSet(Pair::getValue)
```

with

```
Collectors.mapping(Pair::getValue, Collectors.toSet())
```

The problem is that [`Collectors.toSet()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toSet()) doesn't have any parameters, it operates on the type defined by the input stream. [`Collectors.mapping(mapper, downstream)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#mapping(java.util.function.Function,java.util.stream.Collector)) alters this behaviour by "applying a mapping function to each input element before accumulation".